# Como puedo crear un campo especifico para Usuario con SDK de Firebase Admin

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase, express

Estoy utilizando SDK Firebase Admin para la creacion de usuarios en mi aplicacion, estoy utilizando NodeJS y Express. Segun la documentacion para crear un usuario es el siguiente codigo.

```
  getAuth().createUser({
    email: 'user@example.com',
    emailVerified: false,
    phoneNumber: '+11234567890',
    password: 'secretPassword',
    displayName: 'John Doe',
    photoURL: 'http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png',
    disabled: false,
  })
  .then((userRecord) => {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
  });
```

Hay algunos campos que si utilizo, sin embargo, quisiera agregar nuevos campos que me seran util mas adelante. Sin embargo no se si esto es posible de alguna manera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

algunos de los campos (como por ejemplo emailVerified, photoURL) son opcionales. si no necesitas alguno, no lo definas.

esa informacion es necesaria para la autenticacion de los usuarios, es por eso que te lo pide.

si quieres guardar informacion lo tendras que hacer en una base de datos.

```
  const docRef = firestore.collection("users").doc(userRecord.uid);
  await docRef.set({ cualquier: "cosa" });
```

ese es un ejemplo usando firestore (v7), que esta incluido en el Admin SDK.

un saludo amigo!

Comment: Muchas gracias Cristian. Habia buscando alguna otra forma pero con la parte de codigo me quedo perfectamente claro. Un saludo.